# Text box in select option for web app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am building a web app that is used to select drugs and details associated with drugs. There are some sections that allow for options, but the 'other' option requires the input of text as opposed to selecting one of the other options. I am trying to add a text box after a 'other' option is selected.

Here is the entire code that I have been working on. I have tried using javascript and some jquery, but I am unable to get it to work. Any help would be great please.

```
                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Route:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <select id="Quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" required="">
                          <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select A dosage...</option>
                          <option value="PO">PO</option>
                          <option value="IV">IV</option>
                          <option value="PR">PR</option>
                          <option value="Topically">Topically</option>
                          <option value="other">Other (please specify)</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                 </div>

               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Frequency:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <select id="Regime" name="regime" class="form-control" required="">
                          <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Please select  A regime...</option>
                          <option value="Once A Day">Once A Day</option>
                          <option value="BD">BD</option>
                          <option value="TDS">TDS</option>
                          <option value="QDS">QDS</option>
                          <option value="Other">Other (please specify)</option>
                  </select>
                  </div>
             </div>



             <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date of Prescription:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <input class="form-control" type="date" name="prescription" placeholder="(yyyy-mm-dd)" required>
                  </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: Where is your javascript?

Comment: <script>
   $('#sel').change(function() {
   $('#other').css('display', ($(this).val() == 'Other') ? 'block' :   'none');
    });
   });</script>
               
                    
              <input type="text" id="other" style="display: none;" />

Comment: that is what I tried earlier, but it does not work.

Comment: "sel" is id of which element?. I can't see any element having id as "sel"  in your html code.

Comment: There is no element with id `sel`

Comment: Yes I am sorry, but I have been trying different approaches, I don't know how to incorporate it into my code. Could you give me an example of what I need to do with the code I have submitted in my question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look please this [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wyc3wgq6/)

```
$('textarea').hide();
$('#Quantity').change(function()
    {
        var o = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(o);
        if(o=='other') $('textarea').show(); 
});
```

So here are some explanations :

```
$('textarea').hide(); // hide the textarea by default

$('#Quantity').change(function(){  }); // when the user select an option in the #quantity select tag

var o = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); // get the current value of the option selected

if(o=='other') $('textarea').show(); // if the variable o is equal to "other" then show the textarea
```

Comment: @PeeHaa, it 's better like this ?

Comment: Ok thank you so much, but can you explain where I put this in my code? thanks

Comment: Barry, i just added an <textarea> tag in your html and i explained the JS (javascript). the JS must be written beetween <script></script> tags in the <head> of your document, tell me if you need more explanations.

Comment: thanks Melvita, could you please show those changes in my code? I am not sure where it goes, I am very sorry, and thank you.

Comment: Please look at this JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nxkug25b/   i added the head and the body in the example

Comment: One more question if you dont mind. When I submit the completed form it does not pass the data entered in the text box, it displays 'other'. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: yeah it s because we didn't change the value of the option after we leave the textarea, please look this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534123/fill-select-input-with-a-text-input

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: i ll write it tonight or tomorrow, sorry i don't have time right now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Goodnight

Comment: Please, try this one : https://jsfiddle.net/nxkug25b/2/  i added the missing behavior (when user leave textarea, it change the value of the selected option)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84480/discussion-between-barry-mcdaid1982-and-melvita).